# jquery change menu glitch

Tags: jquery, forms, sharepoint

I have dynamic field names that are auto-generated by sharepoint. The functionality I am trying to accomplish is generally easy outside of sharepoint, but with these-auto-generated ids makes things a bit complicated. All I am trying to do is trigger an alert when the menu changes and essentially- alerting the value, So that I know it is working. I have var sec2 for the ID of the select menu. There are to options in the menu: Regional and Enterpise. On change, it is currently only alerting "Reg" for both options and I do not know why.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var selected = $("selected[title = 'LocationCustom Required Field']").val();
var sec2 = $("select[id = 'LocationCustom_4a457955-01c5-44ff-b4c8-722325e680f4_$DropDownChoice']").val();
$("select[title = 'LocationCustom Required Field']").on("change", function(){

//alert(sec2);

  });


   var sec2 = $("selected[id = 'LocationCustom_4a457955-01c5-44ff-b4c8-722325e680f4_$DropDownChoice']").val();
$("select[id = 'LocationCustom_4a457955-01c5-44ff-b4c8-722325e680f4_$DropDownChoice']").on("change", function(){
alert(sec2);

    if (sec2== "Regional"){
          alert("ent");

    } else{

          alert("Reg");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting the value of sec2 initially, and then alerting it through your onchange event, but you aren't reassigning that value.

Changing the value of the select box isn't automatically changing the value of sec2, you need to include that as part of your on change function.

```
selected.onchange(function(){
   sec2 = selected.val(); //this will grab the new value from the select box
   alert(sec2);
})
```